make client send http request for backend flask
I am trying to avoid rate limiting and ip blacklisting while accessing an external api. I want to deploy a flask web app on google app engine.
I need a way to have the client send http requests to the external api (kind of turning the client into a http proxy) so it looks like the requests are from an actual user, not my application, and for the client to send the data back for processing.
here is an overview of the steps.

A user visits my website
The user visits a flask backend route
The backend requires the data from a call to an external Api
The backend somehow makes the frontend send a request, and gets the response from the api back
The backend finishes processing this data and returns render_template

for this api, it is possible to send this request from any origin, i can copy a fetch request in by devtools and paste it in the console on another website and it still works.
Ex:
@app.route('/')
def index(x):
  # make client send request to external api and get resonse
  result = response.text

  # process data
  b = result + 1
  return render_template('index.html', b=b)

tried websocket, somewhat worked but looking for a better solution
is there anyting like a reverse ajax?

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. "so it looks like the requests are from an actual user" suggests that you need to take a look into User-Agent header (here) for that request. This header identifies the client to the server, as in if it's an application or a browser. It has nothing to do with an actual human-being making that request.
In order to avoid rate limiting, you can try proxy rotating. That way each time you make a request, it looks like you are making that request from a different ip. For more information regarding to that, you can peruse the question below:
How to rotate proxies on a Python requests

i am saying the ip appears to be from a real user. Cloudflare often blocks proxy ip and getting good unblocked ones can be expensive. I was wondering if there was any way to just have the client send the requests instead of the server.
